# Can we mock third party object creation or calls?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

For example I have the following handler:

```java
@Component
public class MyHandler {

  @AutoWired
  private MyDependency myDependency;

  public void someMethod(Object parameter) {
    ...
    ThirdPartyClass thirdPartyObject = new ThirdPartyClass(parameter);
    thirdPartyObject.unnecessaryMethod();
    ...
  }
}
```

To test this, I want to write something like this:

```java
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class}
class MyHandlerTest {

  @InjectMocks
  MyHandler myHandler;

  @Mock
  MyDependency myDependency;

  @Test
  public void testSomeMethod() {
    ...
    myHandler.someMethor(parameter);
    ...
  }
}
```

I want to avoid calling `unnecessaryMethod()`. Is there any way to do this?

If `unnecessaryMethod()` is static then I can use PowerMockito to mock it, but can PowerMockito help in my situation?

Comment: Yes, PowerMockito can mock `new`-ed objects as well, using the `whenNew(...)` method; check the PowerMock documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found an answer:

```
public class MyHandler {
    public void someMethod() {
        Utils utils = new Utils(10);
        System.out.println("Should be 1 : " + utils.someMethod());
    }
}
```

Some Utils class:

```
public class Utils {
    private int value = 5;
    Utils () {
        System.out.println("Should be mocked");
    }
    Utils (int param) {
        this.value = param;
        System.out.println("Should be mocked");
    }
    public int someMethod() {
        System.out.println("Should be mocked");
        return value;
    }
}
```

And test class:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(MyHandler.class)
public class MyHandlerTest {
    @InjectMocks
    MyHandler myHandler;
    @Test
    public void testMain() throws Exception {
        Utils utils = mock(Utils.class);
        when(utils.someMethod()).thenReturn(1);
        whenNew(Utils.class).withArguments(anyInt()).thenReturn(utils);
        myHandler.someMethod();
    }
}
```

Console output will be:
`Should be 1 : 1`

[Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13364406/mockito-mock-a-constructor-with-parameter)