# how to mock a constructor?

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, mocking

I have a method in my `MainActivity` and I want to mock the `A` instance :

```
public void some_method() {
    A a = new A(); 
    ....   
}
```

so I tried creating in the `MainActivity` class a method

```
public A createA(){return new A()}
```

and then `some_method` becomes

```
public void some_method() {
        A a = createA(); 
        ....   
    }
```

I tried this

```
    MainActivity mainActivitySpy = (MainActivity)Mockito.spy(MainActivity.class);
    when(mainActivity.createA()).thenReturn(null)
```

but I get this error message

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException:
when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'.
```

Is there a way to mock the constructor ? I tried the a solution `SO` [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13364406/mockito-mock-a-constructor-with-parameter) (18 points at the time of the writing, solution without `Poweermockito`) but I was not able to make this work, because I don't think it is functional

Answer (score 0):

Using Mockito you can not mock constuctor, but with PowerMockito you can.

Problem here is, your spy call has to be on actual instance. You cannot call it in a you call the mocking a class.

```
MainActivity activityInstance = <get your activity instance>;

MainActivity mainActivitySpy = Mockito.spy(activityInstance);
    when(mainActivity.createA()).thenReturn(null);
```

Comment: I know but I did not manage to make `PowerMockito` work with `Android`

Answer (score 0):

I would pass the mocked A object as an argument to some_method(). Also you could create a special factory for A objects then you could mock the factory

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a spy for `MainActivity` called `mainActivitySpy` but you are calling the `when` on an object call `mainActivity` that I presume is not a mock nor a spy. Changing the `when` call gives the desired effect:

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;

public class MainActivity {

    public A createA(){
        return new A();
    }

    public void some_method() {
        A a = createA(); 
        System.out.println("Mock:" + a);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        MainActivity mainActivitySpy = (MainActivity)spy(MainActivity.class);
        when(mainActivitySpy.createA()).thenReturn(null);

        mainActivitySpy.some_method();

    }
}
```