# Unit testing serializability of a class with mocks

Tags: java, unit-testing, serialization, mocking, mockito

I am running into a problem where a mock object of another class is not serailizable while unit testing if a particular class is serializable.

Here is a small program that illustrates the issue. I have a ***Processor*** class that needs to serializable and ***RpcClient*** is a  class that is not serializable. To make *Processor* serializable I have marked *rpcClient* member variable as *transient*.

```
class RpcClient {
  int addr;

  RpcClient(int addr) {
    this.addr = addr;
    // connect to remote service
  }

  // other methods
}

class RpcClientFactory implements Serializable {
  public RpcClient getRpcClient(int addr) {
    return new RpcClient(addr);
  }
}

class Processor implements Serializable {
  final RpcClientFactory rpcClientFactory;
  transient RpcClient rpcClient;

  Processor() {
    this(new RpcClientFactory());
  }

  Processor(RpcClientFactory rpcClientFactory) {
    this.rpcClientFactory = rpcClientFactory;
  }

  public void start(int addr) {
    rpcClient = rpcClientFactory.getRpcClient(addr);
  }

  // other methods
}
```

Now in order to test the *Processor* class, I have the following unit test,

```
@RunWith(JUnit4.class)
public class ProcessorTest {
  private RpcClientFactory mockRpcClientFactory;
  private RpcClient mockRpcClient;

  @Before
  public void setUp() {
    mockRpcClientFactory = mock(RpcClientFactory.class, withSettings().serializable());
    mockRpcClient = mock(RpcClient.class, withSettings().serializable());
    when(mockRpcClientFactory.getRpcClient(any(int.class))).thenReturn(mockRpcClient);
  }

  @Test
  public void testProcessorIsSerializable() {
    Processor p = new Processor(rpcClientFactory);
    p.start();
    // Use some Utils library to serialize and deserialize 
    Utils.deserializeFromByteArray(Utils.serializeToByteArray(p));

    assert(true);
  }
}
```

Running the test fails with an exception,

```
Caused by: java.io.InvalidClassException: ProcessorTest$RpcClient$$EnhancerByMockitoWithCGLIB$$5db6cf07; no valid constructor
```

Of course the problem goes away if I add a no-arg constructor to *RpcClient* but lets say it is a third-party library to which I don't have access to. I understand that *Mockito* clearly mentions, ***The mock can be serialized assuming all the normal serialization requirements are met by the class*** and in my case *RpcClient* doesn't meet the requirements.

But if you look at it, even though my code doesn't expect *RpcClient* to be serializable (marked transient), my unit test forces me to. Is there a way to get around this in my test class?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mockito mock a constructor with parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13364406/mockito-mock-a-constructor-with-parameter). I think your problem is not with the ability to serialize the class, but with the fact that you don't have a default constructor.

Comment: @RobertMoskal looks like that only works with PowerMock. Unfortunately I can only use Mockito.

Comment: No.look in the link to the Mockito documentation. There are many ways around this.