# Mocking variable in method in junit

Tags: java, junit, mockito

How can I mock `clientInstance.execute` if I am writing Junit for the following method?

```
public class ClassName{
    public static <type> fun(){
        HttpClient clientInstance = null;
        // clientInstance initialised here 

        response = clientInstance.execute();
        //I am trying to mock clientInstance.execute 
    }
}
```

Comment: You cannot. You'll need to inject clientInstance into the `fun()` method or make it an instance variable.

Comment: So there is no way to mock clientInstance.execute(), other than modifying the above function ?

Comment: `Mockito.when((Mockito.any(HttpClient.class).execute())).thenReturn(httpResponse)` will it work ?

Answer (score 1):

As [kryger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1240557/kryger) pointed out, you'd better redesign your code for testability:

```
public class ClassName {
    public static <type> fun(HttpClient clientInstance){
        response = clientInstance.execute();
        //I am trying to mock response.execute 
    }
}
```

This is called [dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection). Which is a fancy term for putting the burden on the caller of this code. J.B.Rainsberger wrote an [excellent post](http://blog.thecodewhisperer.com/permalink/consequences-of-dependency-inversion-principle) about it.

If you can't modify the signature of `fun()` because too many other code depends on it, then you can overload it:

```
public class ClassName {
    /* this method is *not* going to be tested */
    public static <type> fun(HttpClient clientInstance){
        HttpClient clientInstance = null;
        // clientInstance initialised here 
        return fun(clientInstance);
    }

    /* this method is going to be tested */
    public static <type> fun(HttpClient clientInstance){
        response = clientInstance.execute();
        // mocking clientInstance.execute() will be easy now
    }
}
```

What if the `HttpClient` initialisation is tricky and you want to test it? You can refactor it into another method:

```
public class ClassName {
    /**
      * Package-private for testing reasons.
      * Do not call it from within the class in production code!
    */
    static HttpClient createHttpClient() {
        HttpClient clientInstance = null;
        // clientInstance initialised here 
        return clientInstance;
    }

    /* this method is *not* going to be tested */
    public static <type> fun(HttpClient clientInstance){
        HttpClient clientInstance = createHttpClient();
        return fun(clientInstance);
    }

    /* this method is going to be tested */
    public static <type> fun(HttpClient clientInstance){
        response = clientInstance.execute();
        // mocking clientInstance.execute() will be easy now
    }
}
```

If everything else fails, you can use [PowerMock](https://github.com/powermock/powermock) to mock constructors. I've never seen a case where it was worth the trouble. Anyway, [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13364406/187808) explains how to use it.

Answer (score -1):

You can create a mock instance for clientInstance using `Mockito.mock` and then define what it returns using `Mockito.when`, like so:

```
HttpClient clientInstance = Mockito.mock(HttpClient.class); // initialize mock
Object mockReturn = new Object(); // define your return object
Mockito.when(clientInstance.execute()).thenReturn(mockReturn); // define what mock returns
Object response = clientInstance.execute(); // call your mock
```

Comment: Sadly, the question wasn't "how to use Mockito?" or "how do I modify my code to make it testable?".