# Mock method return type in java

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

Below is main code consist of one util class and service class using it

```
@PropertySource("classpath:atlas-application.properties")
public class ApacheAtlasUtils {

  @Value("${atlas.rest.address}")
  private String atlasURL;
  
  @Value("${atlas.rest.user}")
  private String atlasUsername;

  @Value("${atlas.rest.password}")
  private String atlasPassword;

  private AtlasClientV2 client;

  public AtlasClientV2 createClient() {
    if (client == null) {
      return new AtlasClientV2(new String[] {atlasURL}, new String[] {atlasUsername, atlasPassword});
    } else {
      return client;
    }
  }
}
```

Service Class is below :-

```
@Override
  public Page<SearchResultDto> findFilesWithPages(QueryParent queryParent, Pageable pageable)
    throws AtlasServiceException {
    //  Some code
    client = new ApacheAtlasUtils().createClient();
   //some code
      
      }
```

I am writing unit test for service method and I am getting exception for createClient method asking for values for url, username and password which should not happen as this should be mocked but the mocking is giving me below error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Base URL cannot be null or empty.

    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:141)
    at org.apache.atlas.AtlasServerEnsemble.<init>(AtlasServerEnsemble.java:35)
    at org.apache.atlas.AtlasBaseClient.determineActiveServiceURL(AtlasBaseClient.java:318)
    at org.apache.atlas.AtlasBaseClient.initializeState(AtlasBaseClient.java:460)
    at org.apache.atlas.AtlasBaseClient.initializeState(AtlasBaseClient.java:448)
    at org.apache.atlas.AtlasBaseClient.<init>(AtlasBaseClient.java:132)
    at org.apache.atlas.AtlasClientV2.<init>(AtlasClientV2.java:82)
    at com.jlr.stratus.commons.utils.ApacheAtlasUtils.createClient(ApacheAtlasUtils.java:40)
    at com.jlr.stratus.rest.service.impl.FileSearchService.findFilesWithPages(FileSearchService.java:49)
```

The Test code is as follows:-

```
 private FileSearchService fileSearchService;

  @Spy
  private ApacheAtlasUtils apacheAtlasUtils;

  @Mock
  private AtlasClientV2 client;

  @Before
  public void setup() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    fileSearchService = new FileSearchService();
  }
  
@Test
  public void findFilesWithPages_searchAll() throws AtlasServiceException {
        Mockito.doReturn(client).when(apacheAtlasUtils).createClient();

   service.search(queryParent,pageable);

  }
```

Comment: And what is your question? Why it is happened?

Comment: Yes and solution if possible

Comment: You call `createClient` on newly created instance, but mock on different instance. You need to mock constructor (it is possible using PowerMockito).

Comment: Using PowerMockito should be your last resort. If you have to it usually means that your design is flawed.

Comment: Any code snippet suggestion

Comment: Did you tried to find them yourself?

Comment: Yes off course I tried

Comment: I googled "java mock constructor" and this is first link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13364406/mock-a-constructor-with-parameter . I think it answers your question. If no feel free to post another one, but please be more specific about your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your idea with spying is adequate (you can even go for mocking if you do not actually need any true implementation of that class).

The problem lies in the implementation:

```
    //  Some code
    client = new ApacheAtlasUtils().createClient();
   //some code
      
      }
```

Instead of having the `ApacheAtlasUtils` as an instance variable (or a supplier method) you create the instance on the fly.

Mockito is not smart enough to catch that operation and replace the real object with you spy.

With the supplier method you can set up your test as follows:

```
  @Spy
  private FileSearchService fileSearchService = new FileSearchService();

  @Spy
  private ApacheAtlasUtils apacheAtlasUtils = new ApacheAtlasUtils();

  @Mock
  private AtlasClientV2 client;

  @Before
  public void setup() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

    doReturn(apacheAtlasUtils).when(fileSearchService).getApacheUtils();
  }
```

in your SUT:

```
@Override
  public Page<SearchResultDto> findFilesWithPages(QueryParent queryParent, Pageable pageable)
    throws AtlasServiceException {
    //  Some code
    client = getApacheUtils().createClient();
   //some code
      
      }

ApacheAtlasUtils getApacheUtils(){
   return new ApacheAtlasUtils();
}
```

Comment: I am bounded to create client instance through util class. I tried to create on method and class level both but no luck.

Comment: client is not he issue here. new ApacheAtlasUtils() is the issue

Comment: I tried this but it failed with same exception:ApacheAtlasUtils apacheAtlasUtils = new ApacheAtlasUtils();
    client = apacheAtlasUtils.createClient();

Comment: Sorry to let you know even after mocking the ApacheUtils class, code is still going into method of class which is causing same exception

Comment: Did you alter the Before method?

Comment: Yes as suggested

Comment: Is the createClient() overloaded in the utils somewhere?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219260/discussion-between-optimus-and-maciej-kowalski).

Comment: Nope this is only method in class