# How to mock dependencies that depend on input value?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I want to unit-test a method like this:

```
public String handleRequest(Event event) {
      for(Message msg : event.getRecords()){
           SDKClient client = new SDKClient(msg.getUser(), msg.getPassword());
           String output = client.makeAPICall();
           return output.toUpperCase();
       }
   }

}
```

Typically, we mock dependencies like `SDKClient` by passing them in as arguments and mocking them in Junit/Mockito. However, in this case, I cannot just pass it because the `SDKClient` depends on the actual events passed in. There is also an undetermined number of clients, one for each message in the `event`. I want to unit test the method as a whole, but I do not know the dependencies in advance. Is it possible?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/13364406/6269962 seems like your question

Comment: @AlexanderIvanov Both that question and its accepted answer are questionable _at best_ particularly since the introduction of lambdas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case, what you pass in is some kind of function that abstracts the `new SDKClient` call:

```
interface SdkClientProvider {
    SDKClient(String user, String password);
}
```

In this particular case, you could use `BiFunction<String, String, SDKClient>` if you prefer.

As `new SDKClient` is likely to be the only "live" implementation of this class, you can even do something like this:

```
class MyService {
    @Setter
    private BiFunction<String, String, SDKClient> createClient = SDKClient::new;

    ...
}
```

This pattern is commonly seen when depending on the system `java.time.Clock`.

(Note that the "create, use, and dispose of a service object" is a very questionable design, and unless you're stuck with consuming some badly-designed external library, it's begging for refactoring.)

Comment: This makes sense. Thanks! I wonder how this would have worked before Lambda functions / Java 8.

Comment: @db-user You could do the exact same thing, but it would have been annoyingly more complicated, and so people would tend to be lazy about it.