# Mock constructor with mockito

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I want to mock a constructor into method.

```
public String generaID() {   
    GeneraIDParaEntidadCliente aux = new GeneraIDParaEntidadCliente(nombre, registro);   
    entidad.setID(aux.generaID);   
}
```

In my test I want do something like this :

```
when(new GeneraIDParaEntidadCliente(anyString(), any(Entidad.class)).thenReturn(generaIdMock)
```

but give me this **error** `org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException:`

Any idea why?

Comment: but eq() is when you mixed anyXXX with object. Or not?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unit testing with mockito for constructors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11214136/unit-testing-with-mockito-for-constructors)

Comment: but this solution doesn´t works for me, I don´t want to parametrice method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

UPDATE: since [since version 3.5.0](https://javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.5.13/org/mockito/Mockito.html#mocked_construction), Mockito can do this without PowerMockito.

You can use [PowerMock](https://github.com/jayway/powermock) to mock constructors.

If you can't use PowerMock for some reason, the most workable solution is to inject a factory to whatever class contains this method. You would then use the factory to create your `GeneraIDParaEntidadCliente` object and mock the factory.

Comment: I tried whith 
org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.whenNewnew(GeneraIDParaEntidadCliente(String.class, Entidad.class).thenReturn(generaIdMock)
But doesn´t work. Any idea why?

Comment: I'd have to see more of your code to know exactly what's wrong. Are you using @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class) and @PrepareForTest on the test class? See [here](http://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockitoUsage13).

Comment: @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class) and @PrepareForTest({GeneraIDParaEntidadCliente .class})

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways of doing this, described in [my article on the Mockito wiki](http://code.google.com/p/mockito/wiki/MockingObjectCreation)

Comment: ha ha ... instead of providing solution ... they are telling to change the code itself

Answer (score 0):

Copying answer from [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11214136/unit-testing-with-mockito-for-constructors):
Mockito can now mock constructors (since version 3.5.0) https://javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.5.13/org/mockito/Mockito.html#mocked_construction

```
try (MockedConstruction mocked = mockConstruction(Foo.class)) {
   Foo foo = new Foo();
   when(foo.method()).thenReturn("bar");
   assertEquals("bar", foo.method());
   verify(foo).method();
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

you can send mocked objects as paramemters to your class constructor, form example:

```
// define you object
public MainClassObj instanceClass;

// mock input parameter
MYClassObj mockedObj = Mockito.mock(MYClassObj.class);

// call construvtor with mocked parameter
instanceClass = new instanceClass(mockedObj);
```