# Mockito mock constructor example

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I'm trying to instantiate a mock object with Mockito. I found two examples in the article [here](https://code.google.com/p/mockito/wiki/MockingObjectCreation), still this article is a very bad example for a newbie like me in Mockito.

Can somebody give me a better example of how it is done with either of the two options?

Comment: https://gualtierotesta.wordpress.com/2013/10/03/tutorial-using-mockito/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mock constructor with mockito](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20286020/mock-constructor-with-mockito)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple when doing PowerMockito

```
public class A {
    private final String name;

    public A(String name) {
        this.name= name;
    }

    public String sayHello() {
        return "Hi " + this.name;
    }}

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(A.class)
public class MockA {

    @Test
    public void testSayHello throws Throwable {
         A a = mock(A.class); 
         when(a.sayHello()).thenReturn("Hi PowerMockito");
         PowerMockito.whenNew(A.class).withArguments(Mockito.anyString()).thenReturn(a);
         assertThat(new A("I am mockcked").sayHello(), equalTo("Yes, you are!"));
    }
}
```

Dependencies

```
<dependencies>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
      <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
      <version>${powermock.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
      <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito</artifactId>
      <version>${powermock.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
    <version>{mockito.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: In the maven repository I couldn't find any PowerMockito library, there's a PowerMock I downloaded it but couldn't that PoweMockRunner.class. Can you tell me which is the correct library ?

Comment: make sure powermock version and mockito versions are compatible. otherwise you may get classloaders issues. Better don't set explicitly mockito dependency in pom file. powermockito jar will internally pick up its compatible mokito jars.

Comment: @kuhajeyan why are you using PowerMockito instead of standalone Mockito?

Comment: It didn't work as I was expecting, to me it looks like mockito shouldn't be used to mock the object creation. Don't know if I'm wrong.