# Mocking a class with native library dependancy

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mocking, robolectric

Iam trying to mock a public class in 3rd party library .

The class looks like..

```
public class TestManagerClass{

   public TestManagerClass( Context context )
   {
       mContext = context;
       mService = new TestJNIClient(mContext);
   }
 .........
}
```

But construction of TestJNIClient loads a native shared library , which leads to crash in my UT.I want to avoid that.
Extending TestManagerClass is not helping as i have no means to getaway with the super() call.

TestJNIClient is a hidden class in a 3rd party library so i cannot mock. (with @hide)

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can you modify TestManagerClass?

Comment: read answer how to mock constructor http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11214136/unit-testing-with-mockito-for-constructors

Comment: TestManagerClass is not owned by me.Suggested solutions are mostly about tweaking the constructor.