# unit test avoid class B constructor call in class A test method

Tags: java, android, unit-testing

I have ClassA and ClassB, i have some instrumentation dependencies instantiated in Class B constructor so i want to avoid Class B constructor being called when testing Class A's foo method. Class A's foo method creates an instance of class B. I am using mockito is there any way to tell test case that when TestClassA.foo() method is called don't instantiate ClassB but return dummy ClassB.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem of mine by delegating the Class B instantiating responsibility to a Factory class. 
Then while testing used mockito to mock the factory class and called the makeClassB() method to get instance of ClassB, also used `Mockito.when(factoryMock.makeClassB(anyParameters)).thenReturn(MockClassB)`

And now in TestClassA i can call ClassA's foo() method which now uses Factory class to create instance of ClassB instead of directly creating ClassB instance.

check this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/21262999/3805770.

Comment: Thanks for posting your solution!