# Mock RestTemplate return null

Tags: spring, mockito, spring-test, spring-resttemplate

I need to mock restTemplate for a simple request:

```
HttpEntity<RequestVO> request = new HttpEntity<>(new RequestVO(),new HttpHeaders());
restTemplate.postForEntity("URL", request , ResponseVO.class);
```

But I'm getting null on `postForEntity` request:

```
ResponseVO respVO = new ResponseVO();
respVO.setEntry("https://www.test.com");
ResponseEntity<Object> resp =new ResponseEntity<>(
    respVO,
    HttpStatus.OK
);      
when(restTemplate.postForEntity(any(), any(), any())).thenReturn(resp);
```

Tried to follow [similar solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57084533/mockito-mock-resttemplate-not-using-returning-mock-value), I'm mocking relevant objects:

```
@Mock
HttpHeaders httpHeaders;
@Mock
ResponseEntity responseEntity;
@Mock   
private RestTemplate restTemplate;
```

**EDIT** Same `null` results when tried similar tries as @JoãoDias suggested

```
when(restTemplate.postForEntity(anyString(), any(HttpEntity.class), eq(ResponseVO.class))).thenReturn(resp);
```

Comment: Have you tried `when(restTemplate.postForEntity(anyString(), any(HttpEntity.class), eq(ResponseVO.class))).thenReturn(resp);`?

Comment: @JoãoDias Same `null` results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Succeeded with [MockRestServiceServer](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mock-rest-template):

```
@Autowired
private RestTemplate restTemplate;

private MockRestServiceServer mockServer;
@BeforeClass
public void initMocks() {       
    mockServer = MockRestServiceServer.createServer(restTemplate);
}
...
mockServer.expect(ExpectedCount.once(), 
              requestTo(new URI("URL")))
              .andExpect(method(HttpMethod.POST))
              .andRespond(withStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
              .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
              .body("EXPECTED")
```

> MockRestServiceServer actually works by intercepting the HTTP API calls using a MockClientHttpRequestFactory. Based on our configuration, it creates a list of expected requests and corresponding responses. When the RestTemplate instance calls the API, it looks up the request in its list of expectations, and returns the corresponding response.

Comment: I have the same issue but I couldn't fix it. How can I fix it? Here is the link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76308882/spring-boot-junit-test-resttemplate-returns-null-in-servicetest