# Mockito junit 5 mock constructor

Tags: mockito, junit5, powermockito

I want to mock a constructor and return a mock object when the constructor is called. This can be achieved using powermockito's whenNew method like this.

`PowerMockito.whenNew(ClassName.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(mockObject);`

Since Junit5 doesn't have powermockito support yet, I need to know if this can be achieved using Mockito.

Comment: I don't think so ```Junit5 doesn't have powermockito support yet``` you need to add an external lib.  Possibly duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13364406/mock-a-constructor-with-parameter

Answer (score 5):

Mockito 3.5 has added alot of PowerMock's functionality into core Mockito. It now has a method, mockConstruction(), that you can use to mock constructors. Reference: https://rieckpil.de/mock-java-constructors-and-their-object-creation-with-mockito/