# How to use Mockito to mock new Object?

Tags: java, mocking, mockito

I have a class that contains a new() call like this:

```
public class TestService {
    public String test(String test) {
        String data = new Engine().getData();
        return test + data;
    }
}
```

I can't modify the code, is it possible using Mockito to mock new Engine().getData()?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mockito - mocking legacy class constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6288575/mockito-mocking-legacy-class-constructor)

Comment: @maloomeister i can't modify the code or  use the PowerMock，so the answer is invalid